# Spring integration application don`t send callback request

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-integration

I have 3 web applications, client, integration service and let's call it server. I need to pass REST request from client to integration service and then redirect that to server. After that I need to make response goes back from server to client through separate spring integration application. Let me explain how it  works. Client web app originates REST request to integration service(spring integration based app), integration service does some logging and analysis and then this bypasses this request to server. That part works fine. But when client gets response from integration service application it gets empty JSON object. I checked, server sends correct JSON object to integration service app but after that it passes empty JSON to client. I guess something is wrong with xml configuration. Could you please advice where I should look at? Below is my spring-integration .xml

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="outboundGateway"
                               request-channel="request"
                               reply-channel="response"
                               http-method="POST"
                               url="http://localhost:8080/findAll"
                               extract-request-payload="true"
            />

    <!---->
    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="serviceGateway"
                              supported-methods="GET, POST"
                              request-channel="httpRequest"
                              mapped-response-headers="Return-Status, Return-Status-Msg, HTTP_RESPONSE_HEADERS"
                              path="/service/findAll"
                              reply-timeout="50000">
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

    <int:router input-channel="httpRequest" expression="headers.http_requestMethod">
        <int:mapping value="GET" channel="request"/>
    </int:router>
```

Answer (score 0):

We just added clarification that `expected-response-type`, such as `java.lang.String` is required; see the note [**Note: expected-response-type** at the end of this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/http.html#http-outbound).